Control CANoe by python with py_canoe library
**Can I change Transport layer of ECU with python code? **
I'm working on CANOoe 11.0 .When I consul this reference I don't see any function code support to change the transport layer of the ECU.
https://chaitu-ycr.github.io/py_canoe/999_reference/#py_canoe.CANoe
My Diagnostic Configure, just approve the new CAN ID address after Extended Section and Security part, before that without change manual, it will become Timeout.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
